# VBA html/javascript scraping by line number or string

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

ers,
I am trying to create a vba based html web scraper to gather some data. The data I am trying to scrape is from javascript that looks similar to this:

```
  <script src="https://d1fkb6ohkxde1z.cloudfront.net/assets/common-bundle-     a24f15b690f23a668028e412a6d5243a1b0eeac497627def104363c0941da290.js"></script>
 <script src="https://d1fkb6ohkxde1z.cloudfront.net/assets/private-57441f796e1722a6986c300e765cb19ea439a663b341a68647ebdb60252a0682.js"></script>

  <script>
  $('#onboardingModal').modal('show')  
  var silo = $profarmer.currentSilo;

  silo.service_url = 'https://prices.profarmergrain.com.au/';
  silo.clear_service_url = 'https://www.cleargrain.com.au';
  silo.bhc_site_name = 'Port Adelaide Zone';
  silo.bhc_site_type = 'PortZone';
  silo.port_name = 'Port Adelaide';
  silo.bhc_site_type = 'PortZone';
  silo.bulk_handler_code = 'Zone';
  silo.bulk_handler_name = 'Port Prices';
  silo.grain_type = 'Wheat';
  silo.grain_season = '2015';
  silo.initBinGradeSelector(true, 'APW1',  [{"code":"APW1","description":"Australian Premium White Wheat No 1","seasons":["2015","2016","2014"]},{"code":"H1","description":"Hard Wheat No 1","seasons":["2015","2016","2014"]},{"code":"H2","description":"Hard Wheat No 2","seasons":["2015","2016","2014"]},{"code":"HPS1","description":"Wheat - High Protein Screenings No1","seasons":["2015"]},{"code":"AUH2","description":"Australian Hard Varieties Wheat (Utility Grade)","seasons":["2015","2014"]},{"code":"APW1 FMG","description":"APW1 Floating Spread Multi-Grade","seasons":["2015","2016"]},{"code":"APW1 MG","description":"Multigrade APW1","seasons":["2015","2016","2017"]},{"code":"ASW1","description":"Australian Standard White Varieties Wheat","seasons":["2016","2015","2014"]},{"code":"AGP1","description":"Australian General Purpose No.1","seasons":["2015","2016","2014"]},{"code":"AUW1","description":"Utility Wheat","seasons":["2015","2014"]},{"code":"FED1","description":"Feed Wheat","seasons":["2015","2016"]},{"code":"SFW1","description":"Stock Feed Winter Wheat","seasons":["2015"]},{"code":"DR1","description":"Durum Wheat No.1 Grade - Protein 13.2%","seasons":["2015"]},{"code":"DR1 MG","description":"Multigrade Durum No.1","seasons":["2016"]},{"code":"DR2","description":"Durum Wheat No.2 Grade - Protein Target 12.0%","seasons":["2015"]},{"code":"DR3","description":"Durum Wheat No.3 Protein No Min","seasons":["2015"]},{"code":"SFE1","description":"Soft Wheat No.1 Grade","seasons":["2015"]}]);
 silo.pricing_label = 'Port Zone Bid';
 silo.port_equivalent = false;
 silo.tradable  = false;
 silo.freight_rate = 0.0;

 React.mount({
 "price-chart": $profarmer.components.PriceChart,
 "price-search": $profarmer.components.PriceSearch,
 "merchant-prices": $profarmer.components.MerchantPrices,
 "clear-grain-prices": $profarmer.components.ClearGrainPrices,
 "market-commentary": $profarmer.components.MarketCommentary,
 }, {
 props: {
 snapshot: {"bhc_site_name":"Port Adelaide Zone","port_name":"Port Adelaide","grain_type_name":"Wheat","grain_season_start_year":2015,"bulk_handler_code":"Zone","bulk_handler_name":"Port Prices","market_prices":{"APW1":{"2015":{"port_price":"266.0","price":"266.0","price_high_movement":"-4.0","prices_last_updated_at":"2016-05-31T06:10:05.000Z"},"2016":{"port_price":"255.0","price":"255.0","price_high_movement":"-6.0","prices_last_
```

And continues with a few hundred more prices in a similar format. Ideally I would scrap everything from the line "props:" onwards. I have a simple code to rearrange the text once in excel, but my vba code to scrape the html/java is having some troubles.

```
   Sub ie_open()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim TxtRng As Range
   Dim ie As Object

   Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")
   ie.NAVIGATE "https://www.profarmergrain.com.au/prices/port-adelaide-zone/Zone/wheat"
   ie.Visible = True

   While ie.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
   Wend

   Dim V As Variant
   Set V = ie.document.getelementbyid("src") ' - need better code here

   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet7")
   Set TxtRng = ws.Range("A1")
   TxtRng = V.innertext

   End Sub
```

I am not sure if there is a better way to scrape an element. Instead of by id or tag, is there a way to scrape by either line number or by  or by a string number?

Cheers!

Comment: Does your code work as intended, or there's something that needs to change in *what* it's doing? If it *does* work as it should, and you're looking for feedback on any/all aspects of your code and/or change *how* it does what it does, then you could [consider posting on Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788).

Comment: Hi Matt, trying to get part of the HTML code by a certain string rather than by tag id or by line number. Code doesn't work currently and I think the problem lies within the Set V = ie.document.getelementbyid("src") line.

Comment: You cut your HTML off at the point where you say you actually want information.